# Write a json to a parquet object to put into S3 with Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet

I would like to write a json object to S3 in parquet using Amazon Lambda (python)!

However I cannot connect fastparquet lib with boto3 in order to do it since the first lib has a method to writo into a file and boto3 expect an object to put into the S3 bucket

Any suggestion ?

fastparquet example

```
fastparque.write('test.parquet', df, compression='GZIP', file_scheme='hive')
```

Boto3 example

```
 client = authenticate_s3()
        response = client.put_object(Body=Body, Bucket=Bucket, Key=Key)
```

the Body would correspond to the parquet content! and it would allow to write into S3

Comment: Use a file-like object and then send the content of the file-like object to s3 with Boto3

Comment: @Apero hello, thx! I already thought about it, using for instance StringIO but fastparquet.write does not allow me to write into StringIO

I could write into a file and then read into StringIO and it would work but I cannot do it inside aws-lambda

Comment: Yeah, I just went through their code and it's pretty basic in terms of possibilities. Sorry but it seems you'll have to write to the file, and then read from the file to send it to S3.

Comment: @Apero But that solution wont work in aws-lambda since I dont have any disk/storage to write into and read after! I would need to use EMR and it is more expensive

Other option is to emule a directory in ram to do the write and read

Comment: Indeed, so I believe you have to either drop fastparquet or not use AWS lambda

Comment: @carlosrodrigues you have ephemeral storage in aws lambda

Comment: @Jan No, I do not have... Besides I was talking about of an operation at my local laptop and s3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write any dataframe to S3 by using the `open_with` argument of the `write` method (see [fastparquet's  doc](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write))

```
import s3fs
from fastparquet import write

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
myopen = s3.open
write(
    'bucket-name/filename.parq.gzip',
    frame,
    compression='GZIP',
    open_with=myopen
)
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Would it be possible to update this with a link to [this](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystems.html) documentation page and a caveat that when using the `file_scheme='hive'` option that a no-op should be provided to the `mkdirs` option to avoid the issue brought up [here](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/327)?